# Given two X509Certificate how to tell if one is signed by the other

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have two serialized certificates in the DB from which I can construct the `X509Certificate`. How to tell if one certificate is signed by the other. I don't want to check based on the `IssuerName` as it is not reliable(for my scenario).

Comment: This is easy to do in Java or in using the OpenSSL command line, but I'm not sure exactly how it's done in C#.  The closest I could find is the [x509certificate2 verify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.verify.aspx) method.  Although I don't understand how it gets the CA cert to use in the verification unless it just looks through the Windows trust store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IssuerName property and Authority Key Identifier extension are the way to find relationships between certificates. Once you match them, you can verify if the supposedly parent certificate is actually the CA certificate of the one being checked. I am not sure that such checks are possible with .NET Framework alone, and our SecureBlackbox does this easily, with one method.